# Javascript LocalStorage is not clearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While trying to google sign out, localStorage showing undefined value. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      localStorage.setItem('googleUserName', JSON.stringify(this.user?.name));
      this.myStore = localStorage.getItem('googleUserName')
    })
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('googleUserName')) {
        this.myStore = localStorage.getItem('googleUserName')
        this.newUser = JSON.parse(this.myStore);
        this.user = {
          "name": this.newUser
        }
    }
  }

   // google signout
  signOutWithGoogle() {
    localStorage.clear()
    this.socialAuthService.signOut()
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Check if you are calling the signOutWithGoogle function anywhere

Comment: I am not calling this function anywhere. Without the line "this.socialAuthService.signOut()" in the signOutWithGoogle, localStorage is getting cleared signOutWithGoogle once triggered.

Comment: Confirm that `signOutWithGoogle()` is getting triggered when it is supposed to. Maybe console.log something?

Comment: Yes, this function is working while triggered but making the localStorage undefined.

Comment: Maybe you should run it asynchronously: `async/ await`?

Comment: Right after you clear localStorage, try and retrieve googleUserName (log the result)
This will let us know if localStorage is clearing everything out properly. If it is, then googleUserName gets re-defined after signOutWithGoogle() is called.

Comment: Why doing `this.user?.name`? The user object is not resolved yet?
You need the user object before trying to store it, I would say that at the execution time the property name of the user object is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me. I solved it in another way 

Answer (score -1):

```
try to change in your code -

localStorage.removeItem('googleUserName');


your code will be updated like 
// google signout`enter code here`
  signOutWithGoogle() {
    localStorage.removeItem('googleUserName');
    this.socialAuthService.signOut()
  }


https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_removeitem.asp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way I solved it in another way 